# Uber universal links not working reliably

Tags: uber-api

**Edit: Turns out the Uber app was botched - see answer below. Leaving this post as a reference for others.**

I noticed that universal links I'm generating don't work reliably - I first thought it was only Android, but I'm also seeing this on iOS now.

Links like this one below just open in the browser when triggering the URL to be processed by the system (I removed the detstination and formatted addresses to get a minimal link, but it's still not working):

```
https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&pickup[latitude]=47.5045573061129&pickup[longitude]=8.71492590755224
```

This is a Xamarin app, I'm just using the built-in `Device.OpenUri(uri)` method, which translates into a native call. That used to work in the past...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my Uber install got botched. I uninstalled and reinstalled Uber, and now the links are working again. Weird, but I'll just pretend that didn't happen ;)